# Splitting NSString in IPhone

Tags: iphone

I create an iPhone application using RSS Feed. I using XMLParsing and get the following result in a String. The parsing string having Html tags. I want to read image tag's src only. How can I read src only from the following String Value?

[image]

How can I read src content only from that string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this... basically use NSRegularExpression class.
http://cocoabyss.com/2010/first-step-with-nsregularexpression/

The example there searches exactly what you want: `src="..."` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use an XML parser. Your best options for iPhone are (IMHO):

1. [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/)
2. [NSXMLParser](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html)